# While installing Android Studio the frame is open, what I do over there?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

In frame I have to give the JDK path.

**Any one tell me what path have to give in the frame**?

The frame is second one while installing the Android Studio.

I already give the following path but it not working:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
```

Comment: If you installed java android studio automatically detects jdk path

Comment: use **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05** in FILE-->PROJECT STRUCTURE--->SDK LOCATION and give this path in jdk.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

is your JDK path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u had installed latest java jdk.
Go to Top Menu **File** and select **Project Structure**

Select the **SDK location** option on the left and enter the path of you JDK in the **JDK location**[image]

Comment: You getting wrong actually this error occur while installing process...the SDK is not installed due to this error

Comment: Please make sure you are installed latest java jdk before installing android studio